# Is there a way to ignore tags in a dustJS template

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, dust.js

We have a lot of spring, jsp and jstl tags in our templates that we wish to include. Can we make dust ignore these tags?

```
<sec:authorize access="!hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
   <a>Blah</a>
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
   <a>Foo</a>
</sec:authorize>
```

or

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parser expression grammar to ignore special delimiters, which would look something like this:

```
= ld [^%] ws* [#?^><+%:@/~%] ws* (!rd !eol .)+ ws* rd
```

**References**

- [dustjs / src / dust.pegjs](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/blob/f5b4bc96f2cd1bc5488396e8e81236c2b3352ae5/src/dust.pegjs#L201)
- [dust.pegjs is a bunch of regexes that output an array](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Inner-Workings#dustpegjs-is-a-bunch-of-regexes-that-output-an-array)
- [peg.js Online Tester](http://pegjs.majda.cz/online)